# awk to parse file and export as variable

Tags: parsing, variables, awk

I am parsing a text file

```
Lines   File Name           Gen LnkLN LINK   Time
----- -------------------- ---- -----  ---- ------------------------
00090 TEST1_1519230912        0 00092 .X.X Wed Feb 21 16:35:14 2018
00091 TEST2_1619330534        0 00093 .X.X Wed Feb 21 16:35:14 2018
```

using code

```
awk '{if (($1 ~ /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/) && (length($1)==5)) {
    if (! c[$4]) TLN=TLN $4 ","
    c[$4]=$4;
    if (! d[$3]) TGN=TGN $3 ","
    d[$3]=$3
    if (! b[$2]) TLNK=TLNK $2 ","
    b[$2]=$2
    } 
} END {print "TLines="TLN,"TGEN="TGN,"TLink="TLNK}' /var/tmp/slink.jnk
```

I get O/p

```
TLines=00092,00093, TGEN=0,0, TLink=TEST1_1519230912,TEST2_1619330534,
```

I have two questions with this. 
First one is I don't understand why value for TGN is being printed twice in the output "0,0,". If file has duplicate value for the field I want only one value in the o/p.
Second, I redirect these o/p into another file and use #source filename.txt command to set these values as environment variables and use them in later part of the script. Is there any better way to use them as variables inside the script rather than creating another file and sourcing it.

Comment: My input file is not showing corectly

Comment: The reason you are getting two `0` values is that even after you've set `d[0] = 0`, `(! d[0])` is still true. Use instead, `if (!($3 in d))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `in` to see if a value is being repeated to avoid the case where the value itself evaluates to false. That is what's happening with your `0` value and why it's being repeated in your output.

```
$ awk '{if (($1 ~ /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/) && (length($1)==5)) {
          if (!($4 in c)) TLN=TLN $4 ","
          c[$4]
          if (!($3 in d)) TGN=TGN $3 ","
          d[$3]
          if (!($2 in b)) TLNK=TLNK $2 ","
          b[$2]
        } 
      } END {print "TLines="TLN,"TGEN="TGN,"TLink="TLNK}' f
```

Output:

```
TLines=00092,00093, TGEN=0, TLink=TEST1_1519230912,TEST2_1619330534,
```

**EDIT**

Above I've kept things close to your original version, but as mentioned in the comments, a more idiomatic and nicer version would be:

```
 $ awk '($1 ~ /^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$/) && (length($1)==5) {
      if (!c[$4]++) TLN=TLN $4 ","
      if (!d[$3]++) TGN=TGN $3 ","
      if (!b[$2]++) TLNK=TLNK $2 ","
  } END {print "TLines="TLN,"TGEN="TGN,"TLink="TLNK}' f
```

**END EDIT**

For setting the variables, this worked for me (where a.awk contains the awk code, above):

```
$ eval "$(awk -f a.awk f)"
$ echo $TLines
00092,00093,
$ echo $TGEN
0,
$ echo $TLink
TEST1_1519230912,TEST2_1619330534,
```